# Amazon S3 with a local Hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3

I have a data of about 40 TB in Amazon S3 which I need to analyze using Map Reduce. Our current IT policies do not provide an Amazon EMR account for the same and hence I have to rely on a locally managed Hadoop cluster. I wanted to get an advice on if its advisable to use local Hadoop cluster when our data is actually stored on S3 ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check out https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/AmazonS3 on how to use S3 as a replacement for HDFS. You can choose either **S3 Native FileSystem** or **S3 Block FileSystem**.